# Working with mathematical operations received as input

Tags: c

Let's say I'd like to receive two mathematical operations from a user (e.g. `+ - %`) and calculate numbers accordingly. Let's also say I can use **one** `if/else` statement to determine precedence (and that all operations have different precedences).

I have several ideas in mind for implementation, and would like feedback regarding which is considered "better" coding (clearer, more efficient, etc.).

1. I could do something like this:

   ```
   if (firstOperator >= secondOperator){
       switch (firstOperator){
           case '+':
               switch (secondOperator)
                   // insert all 6 possible cases
           case '-':
               switch (secondOperator)
                   // insert all 5 possible cases
           ...
           ...
   }
   else{
       // same idea as above
   }
   ```
2. Or I could simply hard-code all options by creating one `switch` for every option of `firstOperation`, and nest a second `switch` in each of those `cases` for all  possible `secondOperation`.

The two approaches are different, and I have one or two more. I would have thought that the first is more "correct" and elegant, but it actually results in more lines of code than the "brute-force" all-out second option.

I would love to hear any input regarding this kind of coding.

**Note:** I'm talking about only very basic C programming (i.e. without using other data structures like stacks, etc. Just the basic `if/else`, `switch`, `loops`, etc.

Comment: Take a look at the [shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Comment: Or maybe [Pratt parsers](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2011/03/19/pratt-parsers-expression-parsing-made-easy/).

Comment: Thanks, I read both ideas and I actually did a similar project in Java using a stack for Polish notation, but I forgot to mention in the question that I'm talking only about very basic programming (edited). No data structures.

Comment: Yes, but the point is that *infix parsing with precedence* is not something that can be accomplished with very basic C programming. Infix parsing ***without*** precedence would be a different matter (although not very useful).

Comment: I know. I did  not mean to ask what is the best way to parse mathematical expressions in C. I'm sorry for the confusion. I just wanted to see if there is a better way of doing what I mentioned, then simply using many `if`s and `case`s. I guess not. Do you think one of the options I mentioned is better than the other?

Comment: Does the second operation depend on the first?  Couldn't you do something like `if (first <= second) { handle(first); handle(second); } else { handle(second); handle(first); }`?

Comment: @JS1 Yes, but the `handle(first)` must be split into 6 options (which operation exactly was entered out of possible 6). Same with `handle(second)`. That's what I did (unless I didn't get you).

Comment: Yes, handle() would contain a switch statement with 6 options.  But in the code you listed, you have (6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1) * 2 = 42 cases instead of just 6.

Comment: @JS1 I'm not sure where the misunderstanding is: Let's say the user entered `3+4-5`. Now in my order, `-` comes before `+`, so it goes into the `if`, and into the `switch(firstOperator)` case relevant to `+`. But now I need another nested `switch(secondOperator)` to identify `-`. How do I identify specific operations without the nested cases?

Comment: @Crumbs or you could just forget about all that precedence if/else stuff and go into proper Reverse Polish Notation implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would have done it, but it depends on your first and second operations being independently handled (which I think should be possible if what you are doing is an expression evaluator).  In my example, I assume there is a queue holding the arguments that were parsed in the order they were parsed.

```
if (firstOperator >= secondOperator) {
    handle(firstOperator);
    handle(secondOperator);
} else {
    // Assuming something like 1 + 2 * 3, with 1 2 3 in the queue:
    //
    // tmp = dequeueArg() makes the queue: 2 3
    // handle('*')        makes the queue: 6
    // pushFront(tmp)     makes the queue: 1 6
    // handle('+')        makes the queue: 7
    //
    int tmp = dequeueArg();
    handle(secondOperator);
    pushFront(tmp);
    handle(firstOperator);
}

void handle(Op operator)
{
    int x = dequeueArg();
    int y = dequeueArg();

    switch (operator) {
        case '+': pushFront(x+y); break;
        case '-': pushFront(x-y); break;
        case '*': pushFront(x*y); break;
        case '/': pushFront(x/y); break; // Maybe check for 0
        case '%': pushFront(x%y); break; // Maybe check for 0
        case '&': pushFront(x&y); break;
        etc...
    }
}
```

What I wrote here probably will not work as a general infix parser with precedence.  It's more an example of how to not use O(N^2) nested case statements.

Comment: Thanks.. I feel so stupid that I didn't think of doing it this way.